# awk: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, awk

I tried to assign the output of an `awk` command to a variable:

`USERS=$(awk '/\/X/ {print $1}' <(w))`

This line is part of the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

INTERFACE=$1 # The interface which is brought up or down
STATUS=$2 # The new state of the interface

case "$STATUS" in
    up) # $INTERFACE is up

        if pidof dropbox; then
          killall dropbox
        fi

        USERS=$(awk '/\/X/ {print $1}' <(w))

        for user in $USERS; do
            su -c "DISPLAY=$(awk '/\/X/ {print $11}' <(w)) dropboxd &" $user
        done
        ;;
    down) # $INTERFACE is down
        ;;
esac
```

However, I get the following error:

```
script: command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
script: command substitution: line 14: `awk '/\/X/ {print $1}' <(w))'
```

All brackets are closed. Where is the syntax error?

Comment: What is this subexpression meant to be: `<(w)` ?

Comment: "line 14"? It looks like the syntax error may be introduced earlier in your script.

Comment: @piokuc: Try `cat <(w)` to see how [`<()` process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) works.

Comment: @piokuc When executed in a shell, it shows me the username of the currently logged in user of the running X session: `~ $ awk '/\/X/ {print $1}' <(w)
orschiro`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming because you are using `#!/bin/sh` and not `#!/bin/bash` that process substitution is not available *(or you have a version of bash that doesn't support process subsitiution, pre 4.X.X)*. Switch to `bash` or just pipe `w` to your `awk` command:

```
USERS=$(w | awk '/\/X/ {print $1}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the essential hint! I did not know that sh does not support  process substitution.

Comment: The piping of `w` to `awk` isn't working for me. I use GNU Bash-4.2

Comment: @bashophil does you system have the `w` command? What error message do you see?

Comment: @orschiro yes `sh` is a *(old)* lightweight shell, if you are using anything fancy you almost certainly want `bash`.

Comment: @sudo_O `w` is working in the terminal and in a Bash-script. But the grepping with `awk` seems not to work, there is just no output (no error).

Comment: I recommend changing your command to be `USERS=$(ps ux | awk '/\/[X]/ { print $1 }' | sort -u)`.

Comment: @bashophil that means the command is working fine but the output of `w` doesn't contain the pattern `/\/X/` which is literally `/X`.

Comment: @sudo_O Yup, lol I misread that part with the X-session. Makes sense now. Ty